# Spring 4, tiles 3 and velocity integration

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity, tiles-3

I tried to integrate Spring 4, tiles 3 and velocity and ended up with the below problem.

It is not able to provide spring messages and it is displaying

$springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code)
$springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code) $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code)$springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code) $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code)$springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code) $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code) $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code) $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code)$springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code) $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code) $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code)

Please provide if any documentation or any solution

Thanks,
Rama

Comment: Is the springMacroRequestContext populated to velocity? Can other velocity variables be resolved?